# Why does my usb HID output rubbish? STM32Cube

Tags: usb, stm32, hid, stm32cubemx, cubemx

I'm trying to make a force feedback wheel, but software isn't my cup of tea.
This is supposed to toggle button 0 and it doesn't.

```
typedef struct{
    uint8_t buttons;
    int8_t relativeMvt;
}steer_t;
steer_t steer = {0, 0};

while (1)
{
    HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_13);

    if(steer.buttons) steer.buttons = 0b00000000;
    else steer.buttons = 0b00000001;

    USBD_CUSTOM_HID_SendReport(&hUsbDeviceFS, steer, sizeof(steer));
    HAL_Delay(500);
}
```

My Report descriptor (this is the first time I'm using one):

[image]

Running that code, the buttons are static "ON" like so:

[image]

They DO change (randomly) only when the "relativeMvt" variable is changed, very weird.

What I've tried:

- Swap relativeMvt and buttons in the typeDef
- Check the report descriptor size etc
- Cry

  #define USBD_CUSTOMHID_OUTREPORT_BUF_SIZE     2

  #define USBD_CUSTOM_HID_REPORT_DESC_SIZE      45

  #define CUSTOM_HID_EPIN_SIZE                  2

What do I have to change to make it work? Thanks!

Comment: Check this tutorial https://eleccelerator.com/tutorial-about-usb-hid-report-descriptors/. It looks like your USAGE_MINIMUM definition is wrong. You must set it to Button 1.

Comment: @veeman This is a good tutorial indeed, I used it to make this but I didn't understand it fully yet. 
I've solved it since then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it. I was missing:

```
#include "usbd_customhid.h"
```

and I forgot the "&" when passing my variables:

```
 USBD_CUSTOM_HID_SendReport(&hUsbDeviceFS, &steer, sizeof(steer));
```

Comment: You should probably enable all warnings. A good compiler will catch this sort of failures and warn you.